# How to disable cable detection in VIA Vinyl HD Audio driver?

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers

My driver often goes mad in various ways. Sometimes it begin to false detect cable plug/unplug periodically. This means my headphones switch off and speakers on and vice versa unpredictable.

How to disable it's "smartness"? I wish all sockets be as they are with no help from automaton violating 3 laws of robotics.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the audio jacks out?  They use a micro-switch to detect if something is plugged in, so if it's gummed up, it may be failing.

Comment: Yes this is possible (but unprobable since effect depends on reboot). But I want it to stop thinking at all. Let it ignore micro-switches! Is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps edit your question and provide your exact make and model of the motherboard, as well as what version of the audio driver and utilities you're using, as well as what you've tried already, and you'll probably have a better chance of getting an accurate answer.